# RPi 4B ACT solid green

Tags: pi-4, act, activity-led

I am new to raspberry pi and I recently decided to get RPi 4B.
Anyways, I was doing a small project and when I finished, I pulled the jumper wires from the breadboard and the wire connected the GND and 5.0v touched which caused the RPi to reset. Now, I don't own a monitor nor keyboard nor mouse, so I just use a VNC server on my laptop. When the 2 wires touched the VNC server got disconnected, so i waited for the RPi to boot up but the LED was solid red and the ACT was solid green.

I searched this forum for help but all I found that the polyfuse just needs time to heal, but i just learned that the RPi 4B doesn't have a polyfuse, It only has an OVP diode.

It's been a couple hours and still nothing, I tried reinstalling raspbian and even tried a new SD card, so is it dead?

PS:Sorry for post being so long. I just wanted to give you all the details

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Pi's are notoriously fragile when it comes to electrical shorts, including the power pins on the GPIO header - at a guess, I'd say you have a dead Raspberry Pi - P.S. the polyfuse does **not** protect your Pi in the case of shorting the power pins on the GPIO, so it's presence or absence makes no difference

Comment: Please check the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151).

Comment: How did you reinstall Raspbian, if you have no monitor/keyboard/mouse? Or did you do it using your computer/laptop to copy an image to the SD card?

Comment: I did it using my laptop

Comment: what did you do on your laptop to create the image

Comment: I used etcher to create the image

Answer (score 1):

Your RPi4B is dead. The fix will cost somewhere between £35 and £55 depending which model you've shot dead.

**Never** pull wires off a powered up Raspberry. Power down first. Check wiring, check it again before powering up.

Answer (score 1):

If the LED blinks 4 times when you power it on with NO SD card is inserted, there is a chance that you have an SD card error: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=250183

> ... had solid red/green lights using a number of different SD cards from different manufacturers ranging from 16, 32 and 64GB. Purchased another Raspberry pi 4 from a different vendor along with another power supply. Same problem with the constant red/green light which would indicate that it wasnt likely a power supply or pi fault. As I had re-downloaded a fresh copy of NOOBS and tested it on a number of cards these also were unlikely to be at fault which only leaves corrupt files on the SD card as the reason.
>
> PC 1 (windows 10) with micro SD card to USB adaptor. Format SD card with Sandisk format tool, copy unzipped NOOBS from External HDD to Formatted SD card - Result: Red / Green constant light (I did at some point of repeated trying get 4 green quick flashes).
>
> PC 2 (Windows 10) with micro SD slot. Format same SD card with Sandisk format tool, copy unzipped NOOBS from External HDD to Formatted SD card - Result: Booted up NOOBS, installed Lakka. Powered off Pi and booted up again. Works fine / No more constant green light.

Otherwise, yes. It's is probably dead.