# Raspberry Pi4B Not Booting - Solid Green

Tags: boot, boot-issues, pi-4

Just got a Raspberry Pi4B, I have tried all night to get this to work and have had no luck. Both the red and green LED indicators are both on, not blinking. I have followed all troubleshooting advice I have seen (new NOOBS, etched Raspbian, recovery.bin) and cannot get it to output anything to HDMI or even get the green LED to begin blinking. Plugging in has never caused the green lights to blink, regardless of whether or not anything else is inserted. Wired devices such as keyboards and mice don't power up when plugged in (no leds in keyboard for instance). Recovery.bin did not cause the green LED to flicker. Did my Pi brick in transport or something?

Comment: Hi @Connor, I installed Rpi4B 2GB Raspbian 10 buster full desktop version release 2019jul10 without any problem.  I use Win10 Win32DiskImager v1.0 to install OS image to 16GB micro sd card.  If you like, you can try my way and see any luck. If still no luck, I can repeat your procedure step by step, compare and contrast things to verify that your Rpi4B is indeed bricked! :)

Comment: @tlfong01 I essentially tried the same thing, using etcher instead and on a 32GB micro SD. I just get no activity from the green LED at all, it is always on, never blinking/flashing. This doesn't seem to be a common problem as far as I can tell.
I will try using Win32DiskImager to install the image and give you an exact step by step

Comment: Hi @Connor, I agree yours is not a common program.  I suggest to do the following to make very sure: (1) Use 16GB, not 32GB sd card, (Yes, I am superstitious!) (2) Use SD Formatter v4.0/5.0 to fully overwrite format (not quick format), (3) Then Win10 to fully format (again not quick format) in exFAT (not FAT, not NTFS), making sure you have about 16BG, not 48MB or something. (4) Only then I use Win DiskManager v1.0, with SHA256 hash, ... Lunch time, see you later, ...

Comment: Hi @Connor, So I created another 16GB SD card and boot Rpi4 without any problem. I am going to create another 32GB card later.  I have captured some screens for your comparison. https://penzu.com/p/ad8cf446.

Comment: Hi @Connor.  (1) If I insert an old stretch card, green led blinks twice or three times and then off for ever.  (2) If I I insert NO card, the green led repeats the following 2 steps continuously: (a) blink 4 times, (b) off one or two seconds.  I never heard about your case, so I agree your problem is not common.

Comment: Hi @Connor, 16GB SD card has no problem.  I moved on to 32GB.  I found the first 32GB not writable, stop after two seconds.  I did the following to rectify: (1) SD Formatter to fully format (not quick format), (2) Win10 standard format to fully format (not quick format) to exFAT.   (3) Then Win32DiskMan to create SD card.  Very surprisingly, I found all three 32GB cards not working, one behaves as "stretch": green LED blinks one or two seconds, then off forever.  Two others behave as nothing inserted, loop forever - 4 blinks + one pause.  I have been using these three 32GB cards for Rpi3B OK.

Comment: One possible cause of solid-green:  When booting one 32GB card, green led blinked for one second, then stayed solid.  But solid green stayed only for one minute, then it went on blinking, finally booted OK.  Wild guess is sold green started when Rpi found a read problem, tried repeatedly, hoping the bad read is intermittent and would disappear after repeatedly reading the same location.   I never experienced this before.  My conclusion is that one cause the seemingly solid green is the result of Rpi repeatedly reading the same memory location, misleading the observer that the  green is solid.

Comment: @tlfong01 The solid green exists even without the SD card, this indicates a hardware issue. This user:https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101050/rpi-4b-act-solid-green?rq=1 has the same problem and seems to have fried his board.  I've tried multiple SD cards at this point. Maybe it got struck by lightning during transport or just mishandled. I was pretty careful to avoid static during setup but it seems the board is DoA. They are sending me a new one. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, "... solid green even nothing inserted" almost concludes that it is hardware/firmware problem, and we can do nothing about it: According to  flakeshake, "Rpi on-chip ROM, secondary (bootcode.bin) and third bootloader (start.elf) are executed on its GPU, one chain loading the other. "The instruction set is not properly documented and start.elf itself top-secret. (Jun 16 flakeshake, https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99473/why-is-grub-incompatible-with-the-raspberry-pi)"  Good luck to your new Pi! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem covered by [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151)

I suggest you try removing the SD Card - where the green LED should blink 4 times alternating with long solid green.

If not you probably have a hardware problem.